# Error when install prometheus to monitor Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am installing prometheus to monitor K8S but I met this error. 
Can you help me?
Thank you so much!!

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", 
GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", 
GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}

helm install stable/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring

Error: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot delete resource "customresourcedefinitions" in API group "apiextensions.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: it looks like the resource `customresourcedefinitions` already exists and can't be delted by the user specified in the error. can you try to delete it manually and try to install again?

Comment: sorry, but do you know how to delete it manually?
sorry, I am just a beginner

Comment: try - kubectl get customresourcedefinitions and then -kubectl delete customresourcedefinitions <name>

Comment: I tried to delete customresourcedefinitions but It still doesn't work with the same notification
    `kubectl get customresourcedefinitions`  
    `No resources found.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical situation when Tiller (server side of Helm setup) is deployed without a service account having appropriate cluster role (cluster-admin).

You need to fix your Helm setup first, to be able to proceed with prometheus-operator installation, as described [here](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#tiller-and-role-based-access-control), or by running the below commands directly one by one:

1. `kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller`
2. `kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller`
3. `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much.
One more link to reference (Enable Helm In Your Cluster)
https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/