# deployments.extensions is forbidden error when running `helm init` command on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Kubernetes Helm and Tiller for my Kubernetes cluster. Currently I installed Helm client by following command,

```
sudo snap install helm --classic
```

And now I am trying to run '**helm init**' command to install Tiller in my cluster. I have my configuration file in **.kube/config** path. And I am running the helm init command. But When I am running this, I am getting the following error:

**Updated Error**

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/docker/.helm.
Error: error installing: deployments.extensions is forbidden: User "system:node:mildevkub020" cannot create resource "deployments" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Do I need to change any cluster information in kubelet.conf? How I can resolve this error?

Comment: Which version of kubernetes are you running? You're using `helm` cli in your local machine or the kubernetes host?

Comment: I am using helm cli version 13.1 in my local machine

Comment: Which version of kubernetes? Are you able to use kubectl?

Comment: When I am using kubectl also getting the same error. I checked with kubectl version command

Comment: Ok. The file `~/.kube/kubelet.conf` most likely is your kubectl configuration that file should be `~/.kube/config`

Comment: Ya. Thank you for your response. That was the reason. Now I am able to use kubectl. But again getting the error when trying to run helm init. I updated in question.

Comment: Can you share your `~/.kube/config` as well and tell us how did you deploy your cluster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192052/discussion-between-jacob-and-esteban-garcia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not initialized helm with a service account.

In rbac-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

**Step 1**: kubectl apply -f rbac-config.yaml

**Step 2**: helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200

**Step 3**: Test the setup with `heml ls`. There would not be any output from running this command and that is expected. Now, you can run `helm create myfirstchart`

Answer (score 0):

Your Tiller Pod needs to run as a privileged service account, with cluter-admin ClusterRole. 
Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076280/error-when-install-prometheus-to-monitor-kubernetes-cluster/55098760#55098760) my answer to similar problem as yours.